# Electric flux of a cube with charge at the center

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-fields, gauss-law

I've known gauss' law that any closed surface with some net charge inside, the electric flux would be q/ε0 , but some professor told us that a cube cannot be a gaussian surface and that the electric flux would be different, as follows:

[image]

And I don't think that is true because the field lines are not perpendicular everywhere as in the case of a sphere, maybe this is some special case that I don't understand?
Which is correct, q/ε0 or that answer in the picture?

Comment: Yeah, so many things wrong with this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cube can be a [Gaussian surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_surface) but the calculation shown is not right. You need to calculate the normal component of $E$ at points on the faces and integrate over them.

Even if this is supposed to be a rough approximation, there should not be two factors of $6$ .